# Derivation of heat equation using Fouriers law, explanation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Im currently trying to understand the whole derivation of the Heat equation from Fourier's Law, and there is one part that doesn't make sense conceptually, and I would like an explanation.

Heat equation: $u_t=k \Delta u +f$

So it's when we are looking at the rate of change in energy w.r.t time.

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int \int_{\Omega} u \ dxdy = \int_{\partial \Omega}J \cdot (-\nu) \ dxdy + \int \int_{\Omega} f \ dxdy$$

where $\Omega \subset C$ where $C$ is a conducting plate.

The integration with $J \cdot (- \nu)$ considers the energy flow through $\partial \Omega$.

The last term is said to consider an external source according to the course literature.

However, it's the last term that does not make sense to me. If said to exist a external source that changes the total rate of change in energy, doesn't that go through the edge $\partial \Omega$ and is then in the integration with $J \cdot (- \nu)$?

How can there be an external source that affects the rate of change in energy, but doesn't go through $\partial \Omega$?

Comment: Calling it an *external* source is misleading. It is often simply called the source term, which may be heat generated during chemical reaction (which one could say is something *internal*, since heat is generated within a particular volume). This source of heat does not flow through the boundary. However, there may be scenarios where the heat source comes from outside the boundaries of a certain region, such as a heating element in a liquid.

Comment: So how would one describe these two terms as conceptually as possible? Because I still do not understand what kind of energy the last term is and how it differs from the first term.

Comment: The first term describes heat flow by conduction. The last term represents heat which is generated or flows in from the boundaries.

Comment: Would you mind giving some concrete examples? Because it still does not makes sense to me. If the first term is by conduction, then how can it flow through the boundary, doesn't conduction refer to flow within the boundaries?

Comment: Here's the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) on the heat equation. You can find examples there.

Comment: It's possibly a typo. It should be *internal* source.

Comment: Okey, that would make more sense! could you give a concrete example of what kind of internal source that could be? If we are looking on a simple conducting plate.

Comment: I provided an answer which considers one dimensional heat flow in a metal rod with internal heat generation. Hope it provides some insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example where heat is generated internally. We derive the equation modelling heat flow in one dimension. We model a metal rod which is insulated except at the ends. The rod is heated uniformly by means of a current and also due to a raised temperature at one of the ends. Now, let $T(x,t)$ be the temperature of the rod at $x$ and time $t$. Let $q$ be the heat generated per unit volume in the rod by the current and be constant throughout the rod.

Now, using Fourier's law of heat conduction, where heat flows proportionally with the temperature gradient we get, from a differential energy balance:

$$ -k A \frac{\partial T}{\partial x} \vert_x + k A \frac{\partial T}{\partial x} \vert_{x + dx} + q A dx = \rho C_p A dx \frac{\partial T}{\partial t}  $$

with $A$ the area of the cross-section of the rod and $k$ the conductivity. Dividing both sides by $Adx$ gives us:

$$ k\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} + q = \rho C_p \frac{\partial T}{\partial t}$$

So $q$ is a term representing internal heat generated by the flow of current.

Comment: Thanks, that made much more sense to me! Thanks for you help!